# Flutter: Create object stream from Hive box

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-hive

I am trying to access some user settings which are changed and accessed throughout the app. To do that, I am using Hive to retrieve user settings from a box. I would like to make that information accessible throughout the app by turning the `UserSettings` object retrieved from `Hive.box('settings').get(userID)` into a stream that will be fed into a `StreamProvider`.

How would I go about turning `Hive.box('settings').get(userID)` into a Stream?

Edit: Here is my code implementation so far:

local_database.dart

```
static Stream<UserSettings> get userSettings {
  return Hive.box('settings').watch(key: userID)?.map((boxEvent) {
    return boxEvent.value; // ========> value is always null from boxEvent
  });
}

static void saveUserSettings(UserSettings userPref) {
  Hive.box('settings').put(userID, userPref); 
}
```

main.dart

```
class Launch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LaunchState createState() => _LaunchState();
}

class _LaunchState extends State<Launch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService.user),
        StreamProvider<UserSettings>.value(value: LocalDatabase.userSettings),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: AuthWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

settings.dart

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsScreenState createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  UserSettings _settings;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _settings = Provider.of<UserSettings>(context);

    print(_settings.useLightTheme); // =====> Always returns null

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: 'Settings'),
      body: Container()
    ),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

By [this issue](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/20) I can assume there is no way to get the initial values on watch, it's possible just with `listenable`:

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: Hive.box('settings').listenable(),
  builder: (context, box, widget) {
    return Center(
      child: Switch(
        value: box.get('darkMode', defaultValue: false),
        onChanged: (val) => box.put('darkMode', val),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: I am planning to use this to implement a favorite option of products. How it will be resource-consuming?

Comment: I never tested with critical applications. But different types of product have different amounts of favorite actions, consider that. Also something can help you is using a [lazy box](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/lazy_box)

Answer (score 5):

Use `box.watch()`

Next is a pseudo code just for example

```
Stream<User> listen() => box
      .watch(userID)
      .map(...) // somehow map your User
      .startWith(box.get(userID)); // initial value before any changes
```

PS If you will stuck in implementation - reach me in comments for help

PS 2: the `startWith` method is an extension provided by the `rxdart` package, so keep this in mind

Comment: I tried to implement your pseudo-code and I can get a Stream, however the initial value of the BoxEvent is always null even though I checked and already have something stored in the box. For some reason, the initial value is always null. Please see post edit