# How to listen to a specific key/value changes in Hive flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have added a new key/value pair inside my Hive box :

```
 await Hive.box("myBox").put("myKey", "myValue");
```

And I have a specific method, let's call it specificMethod(), that I want to execute every time I change the value of that key or to get notified when it's deleted from the box.

Comment: Use `ValueListenableBuilder`. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63975824/14781260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen/watch specific key changes as a `Stream` with the `watch()` like this:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Hive.box("myBox").watch(key: "myKey").listen((event) {
      print("BoxEvent | key: ${event.key}, value: ${event.value}, deleted: ${event.deleted},");
      specificMethod(event.value);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

like the example, you can get the actual `key`, `value`, `deleted` ( returns a  `bool`).

And every time it's changed the `specificMethod()` method will execute.